# OpenJPA Exception related to JDBC Driver and connection URL in TomEE+

Tags: openjpa, apache-tomee, tomee-7

We are facing issue in our application with respect to the persistence configuration. The application runs on TomEE Plus (7.0) and uses Open JPA implementation. Below is the error which we are getting

```
<openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There were errors initializing your configuration: <openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: A connection could not be obtained for driver class "oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" and URL "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//mydburl.abc.com:1881/MYSID.ABC.COM".  You may have specified an invalid URL.
```

We dont' get the above error when using `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`. The `XA` driver settings were working fine on IBM WebSphere 8.5. Is there anything else which we need to configure in TomEE+ to get it working?

**Update**

Adding the `persistence.xml` file as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MySchema" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>myjndi</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.abc.jpa.entity.Tuser</class>
        <class>com.abc.jpa.entity.Taddress</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="tomee.jpa.factory.lazy" value="true"></property>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//mydburl.abc.com:1881/MYSID.ABC.COM" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="userName" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

As mentioned, it works fine if I use `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` as the jdbc driver class

Comment: just checking the basics...have you dropped the driver jar into the TomEE lib folder?

Comment: Yes it's there.

Comment: did you define the datasource resource in conf/tomee.xml or elsewhere?  what does your persistence.xml look like.  can you provide samples of the configuration

Comment: I'm running it from the eclipse IDE. I don't think it takes it from the conf/tomee.xml folder. As I mentioned, when I change the drive class it is working fine. Which means it is taking it from the persistence.xml file itself right?

Comment: Romain at TomEE just mentioned XA stuff on the list at users@tomee.apache.org specifically the notes at the end of this reference http://tomee.apache.org/datasource-config.html

Comment: the thread is here https://openejb.markmail.org/search/?q=type:users#query:type%3Ausers+page:1+mid:76glasgusslhv7yf+state:results